# Capacitor iOS sync fail with ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, node-modules

I'm trying to generate a bundle for iOS but pods throw me this error.
I'm 95% sure that it's a problem with plugins but I can't solve.

I tried to reinstall pods, recreate capacitor ios.
I'm doing it on mac, with new m1's

✔ Updating Android plugins in 25.89ms

Found 2 Capacitor plugins for android:
@capacitor-community/keep-awake (1.0.0)
capacitor-keep-screen-on (1.0.0-alpha.6)
Found 6 Cordova plugins for android
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase (10.1.1)
cordova-plugin-device (2.0.3)
cordova-plugin-file (6.0.2)
cordova-plugin-file-transfer (1.7.1)
cordova-plugin-ionic (5.4.7)
cordova-plugin-whitelist (1.3.4)
enter code here

✔ update android in 65.89ms

✔ Updating iOS plugins in 8.94ms
Found 2 Capacitor plugins for ios:
@capacitor-community/keep-awake (1.0.0)
capacitor-keep-screen-on (1.0.0-alpha.6)
Found 5 Cordova plugins for ios
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase (10.1.1)
cordova-plugin-device (2.0.3)
cordova-plugin-file (6.0.2)
cordova-plugin-file-transfer (1.7.1)
cordova-plugin-ionic (5.4.7)
⠋ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠙ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠹ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠸ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠼ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠴ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠦ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠧ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠇ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i⠏ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod i

✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes):

✖ update ios:
[error] Analyzing dependencies

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
       Xcode : 12.3 (12C33)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories :
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

# workaround to avoid Xcode caching of Pods that requires
# Product -> Clean Build Folder after new Cordova plugins installed
# Requires CocoaPods 1.6 or newer
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  # Automatic Capacitor Pod dependencies, do not delete
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCommunityKeepAwake', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/keep-awake'
  pod 'CapacitorKeepScreenOn', :path => '../../node_modules/capacitor-keep-screen-on'
  pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  # Do not delete
end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
end
```

#### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0_2/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fcocoapods%2F1.10.0_2%2Flibexec%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+missing+compatible+arch+in+%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fcocoapods%2F1.10.0_2%2Flibexec%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle+-+%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fcocoapods%2F1.10.0_2%2Flibexec%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/user/Desktop/Apps/test
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cap update

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2021-01-04T16_37_26_175Z-debug.log

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ffi gem doesnt seem to support the M1 chip yet.

Uninstall cocoapods from brew and then try running the terminal in rosetta mode. Right click terminal, get info run in rosetta. Then install the ffi gem from there by typing:

```
sudo gem install ffi
```

then go ahead and install cocoapods with

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and finally

```
pod install
```

After that you can return your terminal to native, or you can duplicate the application and keep one native and one in rosetta mode.

Comment: How about now? : O

Comment: As per this article, the stable version of cocoapods from homebrew, supports m1 macs:

https://dev.to/staceypyee/installing-cocoapods-on-m1-macbook-air-big-sur-h0l